# Query on activation record in C

Tags: c

Below is a code which I am not understand.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      int num;

      printf("\n Number: " );
      scanf("%d", &num);

      if (num >= 0)
      {
           int abs = num;
      }
      else
      {
            int abs = -num;
      }

      {
          int abs;
          printf("\n Values are %d %d", num ,abs);
       }
      return 0;
}
```

When I enter a number as 4, the output is `Values are 4 4`
When I enter a number as -4, the output is `Values are -4 4`

I am not able to understand how is it able to print the absolute value?. the variable abs defined in the if loop and else loop should have been deallocated after exiting.

Kindly let me know.

Regards,
darkie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hilarious code.

It relies on the fact that all three definitions of abs will be allocated on the same place on the stack, due to compiler optimization.

The third abs has to be random garbag, the garbage turns out to be the result of the previous variable with the same name (the name would not matter).

Answer (score 6):

You are absolutely correct.

Do you see the last block where `int abs` is declared that last time? Notice that `abs` is not initialized, and using uninitialized variables yields undefined results. With your particular compiler, it just happens that you luck out, and block of memory where the new `abs` sits still contains the result from it's (expired) previous scope.

Answer (score 1):

These variables are allocated on the stack yet you didn't modify it, I mean you didn't get out of the function, so yet, programmatically you'll get a "new" 'abs' int in the last code block, but in reality, this "new" 'abs' int is in the place where the old 'abs' was (on the STACK!), thus, its default value is the same.

Comment: Are you sure this is the reason? I mean, how do you know that the new 'abs' and the old'abs' are located at the same address on stack?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Google for a freeware application called Olly Debugger. Open up your application, or something like Notepad.exe. It'll stop at the program's starting location. At the bottom of Olly's screen you'll see two panels - on the left its the program's memory, raw, and on the right you get to see the raw stack. Now hit F7 several times and see the stack changes. Read about "stack" on wikipedia to understand more. Once you get the idea you'll completely understand what I answered. Ask more if needed.

Comment: By the way - I was NOT able to reproduce this behaviour with the MSVC++ 2008 compiler (not debug nor release builds) which teaches us that this is a compiler-dependent behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

That's called "undefined behavior".

You're getting "stack trash" when you declare the `abs` with the `printf`.

It works like this:

```
if (num >= 0) {
  create 'abs' at memory address N, put 'num' in it.
  destroy 'abs' // but leave the 'garbage' at memory address N
} else {
  create 'abs' at memory address N, put '-num' in it.
  destroy 'abs' // but leave the 'garbage' at memory address N
}

{
  create 'abs' at memory address N, don't put anything in it.
  // your compiler has decided it will reuse N.  That's a valid choice.
  // your compiler has decided it will not zero the memory at address N.  That's valid.
  read whatever was at 'abs'.  // it's whatever was assigned in the conditional.
}
```

Always compile with `-Wall` :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using an uninitialized value of abs in the printf. The C language standard doesn't require it to be anything in particular because it's uninitialized. It could be 0, or 1, or -32765

In this particular case, you're probably getting the same number because the compiled code is reusing a register for the temporary values of abs, and that same register again for your abs variable in the printf block.

You can look at the disassembly code to see exactly what the compiler is doing in terms of machine instructions.

Comment: Just a little addition from the dept of redundancy dept... I meant disassembly. Or is "Disassembly code" a question?


Compiler compiles to machine instructions, most toolchains have some tool to disassemble the instructions back into some form of more human readable assembly language so you can see what the compiler decided to do with your C code at a low level.  (Apologies if I'm being tone deaf and you already knew...)